# Many flows to one URL caller - How can I set a variable by each flow path to be read in the URL

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm fairly new to Nifi and have not had much luck finding an answer so I'm posting my question here.

In the flow I have, I need to be able to set a variable by each flow path so the URL that is called is modified. I've created a crude drawing to show what I'm trying to do where I need to be able to set a variable, let's call it {target} based on the flow that comes in.
The flows that come in are from a Splitter as I'm reading in file data.

1. How do I even create a var {target} to set?
2. How do I get each flow path to set the {target}?
3. What do type of processor do I need to add for this to happen?

[image]

Comment: the drawing is nice ) however i'm not sure i got you question. probably you are talking about flowfile attributes. you can use `UpdateAttribute` to set the value of named attribute. and later you can use this attribute in nifi expressions like `http://.../${target}`

Comment: @daggett the flow is using the GetFile and the ListFile to FetchFile flow. I'll look and see what it provides in way of setting attributes.